# Error while running Easy2Boot - get_diskinfo ERR=0

Tags: multi-boot, grub

I have created an [Easy2Boot](http://www.rmprepusb.com/tutorials/72---easyboot---a-grubdos-multiboot-drive-that-is-easy-to-maintain/e2bv1) flash disk.

I have a single W7.iso in the correct location: _ISO\Windows\Win7

On the last screen, I get to select an Unattend.XML file

Either the Easy2Boot default, or Sample.xml file.

I haven't created any of these files, and the E2B site isn't clear on them either.

No matter which one I select, I get an error:

> get_diskinfo err=1

Anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

How did you prepare the flash drive?
Is the error message a grub4dos error message or a Windows/WinPE error message?
Is the flash drive Removable type of fixed/Local disk type?
As it works for others, you need to give exact details on how you prepared the drive, what drive it is, etc.
What is the state of other drives in the system (e.g. the internal hard disks)?